# Not able to test REDIS on SuSe

Tags: linux, configuration, redis, opensuse

I have just installed REDIS on our SuSe disto, and the install went fine, make test passed without errors, etc...

However, am now trying to just do a redis-cli ping however, nothing happens, same thing when I try to run any other commands.

A bit stuck since it's not showing me any errors or anything...

Has anyone else experienced this issue and have some insight into how I can get passed it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the issue so rather than installing the current stable version I installed a specific version after  a thorough uninstall I installed version 2.6.16. All working now so odd...